can't connect to socket.io after configure nodejs on port https
I deployed nodejs app on aws-ec2 and run the app using docker-compose.yml.
I use nodejs image, nginx image and ssl certificate from certbot.
Now, I can access nodejs server on https but i can't access socket.io
docker.compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    image: melewasy/backend
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 2s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 1s
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ['npm', 'start']
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem:/app/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem:/app/privkey.pem
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem:/etc/nginx/conf.d/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem:/etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem
    depends_on:
      - backend

nginx/default.conf
server {
  server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://backend:443;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/privkey.pem;
}

src/index.ts
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import https from 'https';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import {env} from './config/env';

const app = express();

app.use('/healthz', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: `app runs on port 443 in environment ${env.environment}`,
    protocol: req.protocol,
    host: req.hostname,
    url: req.url,
    original_url: req.originalUrl,
    ip: req.ip,
    session: req.session,
    headers: req.headers,
  });
});

const server = https.createServer({key: fs.readFileSync('/app/privkey.pem'), cert: fs.readFileSync('/app/fullchain.pem')}, app);

server.listen(443, () => {console.log('server runs')})

const io = new Server(server, {cors: {origin: '*'}, transports: ['websocket']})
io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  socket.on('message', (data) => {socket.emit('response', {message: `hello from server your socket_id = ${socket.id}`})});
});

When i try to connect to socket.io on https://example.com or wss://example.com
nginx log error
nginx_1       | 2024/04/08 12:44:24 [error] 29#29: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 197.35.226.159, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.2:443/", host: "example.com"
nginx_1       | 2024/04/08 12:44:24 [warn] 29#29: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 197.35.226.159, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.2:443/", host: "example.com"
nginx_1       | 2024/04/08 12:44:25 [error] 29#29: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 197.35.226.159, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.3:443/", host: "example.com"
nginx_1       | 2024/04/08 12:44:25 [warn] 29#29: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 197.35.226.159, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.128.3:443/", host: "example.com"
nginx_1       | 197.35.226.159 - - [08/Apr/2024:12:44:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "-" "-"

when i try to send get request https://example.com/healthz , i got this response
{
    "message": "app runs on port 443 in environment production",
    "protocol": "https",
    "host": "example.com",
    "url": "/",
    "original_url": "/healthz",
    "ip": "::ffff:192.168.112.4",
    "headers": {
        "connection": "upgrade",
        "host": "example.com",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.37.3",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "f4258a7d-7b12-49ca-a21b-042f6a3b7044",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"
    }
}

